# Bash script to ensure only one instance of a script running & others waiting

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a bash script `runner.sh` which invokes another `script.sh`. `script.sh` is invoked only from `runner.sh`. I can have only one instance of `script.sh` executing at a time. If multiple invocations of `runner.sh` is made then `runner.sh` should make all the caller's wait if `script.sh` is already running. Once `script.sh` is completed then it will  allow one of the waiting callers to execute `script.sh`.

Can someone suggest some ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man flock](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-flock/):

> [ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0"
> "$@" || :
>
> This is useful boilerplate code for shell scripts. Put it at
> the top of the shell script you want to lock and it'll automatically
> lock itself on the first run. If the env var $FLOCKER is not set to
> the shell script that is being run, then execute flock and grab an
> exclusive non-blocking lock (using the script itself as the lock file)
> before re-execing itself with the right arguments. It also sets the
> FLOCKER env var to the right value so it doesn't run again.

Put this on top of `./script.sh` (or on top of `runner.sh`) and your're good to go.

Comment: Won't this fail rather than wait if it can't get a lock? To make instances wait rather than fail, wouldn't you just drop the `-n`?

Comment: @PaulHodges - If I drop `-n` will the caller wait in the order in which they tried invoke the locked command ? or the order can be random?

Comment: Depends on how it's implemented. Can't say I know. Worth some research if it matters.

Comment: The processes are scheduled by the scheduler. Whichever process gets the CPU time first after the flock has been released will get the lock and continue execution. In short: it's random. You would need to create smth like a  "waitqueue" to get them to order themselve.

Comment: However, according to this [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636127/flock-locking-order) looks like they are woken up in the same order they were blocked. `The documentation doesn't require this but
 * it seems like the reasonable thing to do.` It's still present in [current kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.4/source/fs/locks.c#L682). So I guess you can (currently) count that they will wake up in the same order on linux kernel.